# rabbitmq channel should be reserved for consumers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I have a pool of Rabbitmq `channels` and I have some `queues` and `consumers`.

this way I can get a channel:
`var channel = concurrentChannelPool.Get();`

And whenever my work is done with that `channel` I call `concurrentChannelPool.Return(channel);`

The `concurrentChannelPool` may call `dispose` on the channel for some reasons I defined before.

Now my question is, can I return a channel used to register a consumer?

What happens when we register a consumer and then remove the channel used for that. that consumer gets messages or not?

Here is how I register a consumer:

```
var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += async (ch, ea) =>
{
    var body = ea.Body;
    // ... process the message
    var bodyString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body, 0, body.Length);

    await eventHandler(ea.BasicProperties, bodyString);

    if (!autoAck)
    {
        channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
    }

};
String consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, autoAck, consumer);
```

I'm using this pool on my dotnet core app as a service so I need a channel pool for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the channel is not closed, you can return it. There is a danger to that, because if your channel closes, all the consumers will stop as a consequence.

Generally, you want only a channel per queue, which implies one consumer per channel. However you could open multiple consumers on that channel, on the same queue, in order to increase throughput.

Usually for consuming related channels, you see them in the same place where the consumer is created, because you want to handle the error events, reconnections or circuit breakers.

Channel pools are mainly used for publishing when you want to re-use channels to get around the thread-safety aspects of rabbitmq in .NET

There are nice, open-source libraries where you can look and learn from.
[Here](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RabbitMQ/blob/master/src/NServiceBus.Transport.RabbitMQ/Receiving/MessagePump.cs#L93) is NServiceBus consuming with a channel and [here](https://github.com/snatch-dev/Convey/blob/master/src/Convey.MessageBrokers.RabbitMQ/src/Convey.MessageBrokers.RabbitMQ/Internals/RabbitMqHostedService.cs#L118) is Convey. (highlighted for you the place where the channel is created)